# App ID for iOS Distribution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to submit my app to the App Store. 
While Creating iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution, what App ID should I select? Is it the same as for Development Profile ? Could you please guide me. Thank you.

I already referred http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I create a new App ID each time I am ready to submit a new (no updated) app to the store.

From the portal, go to the "App IDs" tab.

Click on the "New App ID" button.

Under "Description": The common name should be something for you; I often use the App Name followed by "iPhone" or "iPad" or "Universal" as applicable.

Under "Bundle Seed ID (App ID Prefix)": Choose Generate New.

Under "Bundle Identifier (App ID Suffix)": As instructed, use something like com.domainname.appname. Remember this and add it to the Info.plist file  under "Bundle identifier" in your app or you will not be able to upload it.

Comment: Thanks for the info...I followed the steps to create the Distribution profile. However before changing the Identifier in XCode, should it be showing green icon in Organizer (i.e. when I download the Distribution profile created in the IOS portal and drag it to XCode)

Comment: It says "cannot be installed on devices" for me

Comment: -1 You've given a very precise answer doesn't even mention some quite important details like wildcard app IDs.

Comment: @hmthur: clean all targets, then delete the "build" directory. that usually clears up the problem for me.

Comment: @occulus: Yes, because I prefer not to use them. Are we really docking answers for being precise and not covering everything possible?

Comment: @PengOne: I did try that..But that does not help..See my issue is basically with the distribution profile not being accurate..

Comment: Also I am confused whether same App Id can be used for both development and distribution profiles?

Comment: Yes to "Also I am confused whether same App Id can be used for both development and distribution profiles?"... For the profiles, make sure everything is consistent in your Project Settings, otherwise no idea what's wrong. Good luck!

Comment: One more idea... I had a similar problem that someone helped me solve a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124962/help-determining-why-xcode-failed-to-upload-myapp-app-to-my-ipad

Comment: @PengOne Sorry, you're right, that was over the top; have attempted to remove the downvote, but now your answer is locked unless it's edited. You could edit it and mention wildcards and point at this link or similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555043/wildcard-app-ids-for-iphone-ipod-touch-apps  Then I can get at it and remove downvote (and will vote it up).

Comment: @PengOne Downvote removed. My original point was that although you might not use a wildcard app ids yourself, maybe you shouldn't assume that's the best for everyone and ignore that concept in your answer -- it's an important app id concept as relating to app push notification etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use the same app ID you used for development. The app ID is the application identifier -- it doesn't change according to the way you build the app.

Comment: Any idea where to find this value?