# Creating explicit app id for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, explicit

How to create explicit app id for iPhone application that wants use some Store technologies? Do we need to do it in Portal or in XCode project settings? App Id has the format com.comanyName.productName. What should be the format for explicit App Id?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) and also in the Xcode - you need to make sure, the App ID is **same in both places!**

Best practice is [country code].[your company].[optional-project].[app name]

Country code meaning - if you're from Czech Republic, or Slovakia, it is probably better for you to go with **cz** or **sk**, rather than **com**.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315425/app-id-for-ios-distribution) may also help you how to do it in the portal.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My question is: How an external app id is identified as external? We add the App Ids in the Portal for which we want to create Profile. How this App Id and external App Ids are distinguished?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea what you mean by external, could you try to explain it?

Comment: I am sorry that I mentioned it wrong, it is not external, it should be explicit

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ProvisioningStoreTechnologies/ProvisioningStoreTechnologies.html

Hit cmd + F / ctrl + F and search for 'explicit' - I hope you find this link helpful :)